# No :main namespace specified in project.clj

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I just started [Web Development with Clojure](http://pragprog.com/book/dswdcloj/web-development-with-clojure) but I am stuck with a real simple problem. I have `:main myapp.core/foo` in the `project.clj`

```
(defproject myapp "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]]
  ;; this will set foo as the main function
  :main myapp.core/foo)
```

but when I run `lein` I get this error:

```
C:\Users\a>lein run First
No :main namespace specified in project.clj.
C:\Users\a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`First` is an argument being passed to the main function of the namespace specified in `C:\Users\a\project.clj`.  Did you want `C:\Users\a\First\project.clj`?  If so, `cd` into that directory first.